# How to identify a 4K or 16K RAM chip in an Apple II Plus

Tags: memory

Looking at the chips installed in an Apple II Plus motherboard, is there a way to tell which chips are 4K RAM chips and which are 16K?

Comment: By the numbers printed on them?

Comment: IIRC the 2116 was a standard for 16k, don't recall the prefix though.

Comment: fact check: the 2116 *chip* was a 1K x 4 bit static ram; there appears to also have been a 16K x 8 RAM board employing 32 of the buggers, bearing the designation CCS 2116. At the time, static ram was considered expensive, and I believe the Apple used dynamic ram, like some contemporary machines. The 4K dynamic chips needed three supply voltages.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site](http://www.myoldcomputers.com/museum/comp/appleii.htm) the Apple II used [TMS4116-20](http://www.speccy.org/hardware/datasheet/4116-15.pdf) DRAMs for the 16k chips, although I cannot find any references I'd assume the TMS4104 was used for 4k versions.

The full schematics for are available in the [Apple II Reference Manual](http://www.downloads.reactivemicro.com/Public/Apple%20II%20Items/Hardware/II_&_II+/Schematic/Apple%20II%20Schematics.pdf).

Comment: the 2+ I used to have had 4116 chips in it